# dropdown menu with multi selection in swift 3

Tags: drop-down-menu, swift3

I want `dropdown` menu in `swift3` like this i tiered to googling but no any dropdown with multiselection found. i found dropdown in objective c i want like this... i have created my own but if any pods found than it easy implement,because i want it today

**That i found in objective-C**

[image]

**Please suggest me**

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 .Create Child VC and use this code on button click you wanted to open drop down.

Note : dont forget to decrease the opcacity of view of the chil VC

2. adds CategoryVC as child VC .

I added image left side of label but you can add right of label as per image of your requirement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyzWP.png) storyboard view

output view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uHGQ.png)

3. create your header with label and button and from drop down take one tableview. customize cell like this. The box left side of label you are seeing, its simply a button and give images this button on dafault and selected state from the story board.
4. in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, manage the select and unselect button state by true and false only.(to show user image is already selected or not) or take a image with tick mark, use property hide/show.

4 in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, switch the particular selected state of button as selected and normal. Or hide and show the image.

5. Now remove your child VC from your parent on the done button

**Note:** To pass data from child VC to parent VC you have to use delegate-protocol and callback closure.

If you need any other help, you can ask.

Comment: Thanx @Tinu Dahiya but i already mention that i have created my own but if any  pod availabe than i go with this

Comment: If you have to use same drop down in multiple VC, then do the same code by creating xib rather than childVC. for any other help you can ask.

Comment: yaa Sure.. and i am uising storyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}} >
            <Text style={divider}>English  </Text>
            {selectedIndex === 0 ?<Image
                    source={RIGHT_GREEN_ICON}
                    style={{width: 16, height: 16,right:20,position:'absolute'}}
                />
                : null
            }
    </View>,
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row' ,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}} >
            <Text style={divider}>हिन्दी  </Text>
            {selectedIndex ===1 ?<Image
                    source={RIGHT_GREEN_ICON}
                    style={{width: 16, height: 16,right:20,position:'absolute'}}
                />
                : null
            }
    </View>,
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this third party as a **multiselection** or single selection **Drop Down**:

[RSSelectionMenu](https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu)

***How to use it for multiselection drop down as a action sheet:***

```
    func showMultiSelectionActionSheet(simpleDataArray:[String],textField:UITextField){
            let selectionMenu = RSSelectionMenu(selectionStyle: .multiple, dataSource: simpleDataArray) { (cell, name, indexPath) in
                cell.textLabel?.text = name
                cell.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4669097662, green: 0.8560531735, blue: 0.3897160292, alpha: 1)
            }
            //customization selection of row
            selectionMenu.cellSelectionStyle = .checkbox

            // show as actionsheet
            selectionMenu.show(style: .actionSheet(title: nil, action: "Done", height: nil), from: self)

            //dismiss handler
            selectionMenu.onDismiss = { [weak self] selectedItems in
                textField.text = selectedItems.joined(separator:",")
                // perform any operation once you get selected items
            }
            // show message 'No data found'
            selectionMenu.showEmptyDataLabel()
        }
```